# Adicionar Favicon ao meu website

Tags: javascript, css, html

Se eu estiver acessando um site, tanto no desktop quanto mobile, existe a opção de adicionar o link a tela inicial, e alguns websites, adicionam o link com um ícone personalizado.

Ex: Stack

[image: Adicionando o link para o Stack como exemplo]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora o meu site por exemplo não tem icone configurado e vem um padrão do navegador.

[image: meu site link]

[image: meu site sem icone]

Como eu faço para configurar isso no meu site?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar o favicon na sua página

**O que é o favicon? (Wikipédia)**

> Os favicons são pequenas imagens (normalmente 16 por 16 pixels) que
>   ficam guardados no site para visualização pelo navegador. Geralmente
>   são utilizados como logotipos em tamanho reduzido, nos sites de
>   empresas, entidades e marcas quaisquer. Um exemplo é o "W" que aparece
>   no browser quando se acessa a Wikipédia.

Existem na internet diversos geradores de favicon gratuitos que você pode utiliza-los de forma muito simples.

[Aqui é um exemplo](http://www.favicon-generator.org/) que eu mesmo uso

Depois de acessado, basta selecionar a imagem que você deseja que seja o favicon de seu site e selecionar a opção:

***Generate icons for Web, Android, Microsoft, and iOS (iPhone and iPad) Apps***

Espere o processamento de criação do favicon.

Depois clique no link: ***Download the generated favicon***
Feito isso, um arquivo .rar será baixado com diversos favicons que se adaptam aos dispositivos.

Logo depois, extraia esses favicon's para a pasta do seu projeto e copie as instruções de chamadas criadas pelo gerador.

As instruções devem ser **semelhantes** a esta:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Repare que quando você for salvar o site em sua área de trabalho o ícone escolhido por você estará la.

Também repare que o ícone está presente do lado do título da página na aba do navegador.

*Lembre-se que você deve corrigir os caminhos da chamada, caso o contrário não irá funcionar.*

Answer (score 0):

Como a [resposta do @Bsalvo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226515/85842) sugere, você precisa inserir uma tag específica dentro da tag `<head>` de toda página do site para referenciar seu ícone. Melhor da preferência pra um nome mais genérico pro arquivo para você poder mudar a resolução e o tipo de arquivo quando quiser.

Exemplo:

```html
<head>
  <!--Sugiro ou colocar o ícone na raiz do site ou usar uma variável javascript para guardar a string do endereço raiz-->
  <script>
    function Endereco(){
      var caminho = "/raiz_do_projeto/";
      document.write(caminho + "/favicon.png");
    }
  </script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Endereco();">
</head>
```